# Print word that doesn't contain character

Tags: grep, sed

My file is in the following format:

```
this!,is!,another!,test,yes!
this!,is!,another!,column,yes!
no,not!,another!,column
```

My output should be:

```
test
column
no
```

It shouldn't contain the '!' character.

I've tried multiple sed and (e)grep commands but none of them are quite working.

Comment: Doesn't contain which character? If “!” then the last word why is not included in the sample output?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I also updated to add the code blocks for easier reading.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
tr ',' '\n' < file.txt | grep -v \!
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to give the output asked for (separates output with newlines instead of spaces).

Comment: the output in the OP's example is separated by newlines.

Comment: @TimKennedy Hm, it wasn't when I looked.

Comment: btw this solution is the best in speed. I've tested all variants from answers and for 5000 iterations tr+grep took 1st place with 16.194s. next one is gnu grep with 19.171s. 3rd place pure sed 20.514s. 4th awk (22.211s), then perl (46.068s) and the last one is shell+sed (714.402s).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you really meant...

```
test
column
no
column
```

...here's an `awk` solution:

```
awk -v RS=, '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i !~ /!/) print $i; }'
```

Answer (score 3):

requires GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '(?<=^|,)[^!]+(?=,|$)'
```

based on your input, that reports:

```
test
column
no
column
```

If you don't want "column" to appear twice: `grep -oP '(?<=^|,)[^!]+(?=,|$)' | sort -u`

Comment: Be careful, the manual says perl regex support is highly experimental... http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/grep-Programs.html#grep-Programs

Answer (score 2):

Perl is made for these kind of tasks. How about this perl (v5.10 and above) one liner:

`perl -aF, -nE 'for (@F) { say $_ unless m/!/ }'`

- -a   for autosplit mode
- -F,  split input lines on comma
- -n   automatically insert code to iterate over input lines, do not automatically print
- -E   execute supplied per code in the loop

If you have an older perl, just do this: s/-E/-e/, s/say/print/

Answer (score 1):

assuming your text file is `test.txt`, the following:

```
for word in $(cat test.txt | sed -e 's/,/ /g'); do if [ ! "$( echo "$word" | grep '\!' )" == "$word" ]; then echo "$word"; fi; done
```

gives me:

```
test
column
no
column
```

Comment: It's worth noting that process substitution mangles input. (Also, there's no need to create subshells from `cat` and `echo`, you can just use herestrings/heredocs.)

Answer (score 1):

also there is solution in pure sed

```
sed 's/\([,]\)*[^,]*![^,]*[,]*/\1/g;s/,$//;s/,/\n/g' file.txt
```